# Why isn't my Django template properly calculating the length of my collection?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

In my view:

```
posts = Post.objects.all()
print len(posts)
```

prints '2'

In my template

```
{{ posts|length }}
```

results in '0' in the browser

Comment: Did you pass the list `posts` to your template?

Comment: Please, show us the view where is your code above

Answer (score 1):

1)Are u sure, that posts are available in template?
2)Why don`t u use count?